# Slow performance and crashing problem

Tags: 14.04, lts, system-requirements

My Samsung netbook (Model Number : Samsung NP-NC108-PO1BD) has 2GB RAM and a 1.6GHz Intel Atom dual core processor.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit version). After the successful installation it is having problems like slow performance, crashing after boot, etc.

I would like to know which distro would be perfect for me. More specifically I have to use it for doing assignments (editing Word, Excel, PowerPoint, pdf making/editing, pdf to doc conversion, etc.). In addition, a little bit of multimedia purposes like web surfing, YouTube and so on. Finally, I am extremely bored with Microsoft and want to switch to Linux completely.

What should I do now? I certainly do not want to go back to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problems with a somewhat old brazilian Intelbras notebook. And I just downloaded the lighter LUbuntu. Porteus Linux also works fine and saves me from time to time whenever I get some weaker machine, or face compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have many other *Ubuntu* flavors to choose from:

[Ubuntustudio](http://ubuntustudio.org)

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net)

and

[Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)

are all designed to be able to run on computers with limited resources.